# Pass list to AES key generator in PyCrypto

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, pycrypto

I'm attempting to generate an AES key with Pycrypto but receive the following error:

> TypeError: 'list' does not support the buffer interface

for the following statement:

```
aescipher = AES.new(mykey, AES.MODE_ECB)
```

`mykey`, is of type `list` and contains `[1885434739, 825373440, 0, 0]`

Does anyone know how I can convert `mykey` into the correct type for the `AES.new` function?

Comment: How did you obtain the list? The first argument to `AES.new` should be a string.

Comment: @unutbu it comes from this function (which is working correctly) http://pastebin.com/KBzzadNu

Comment: I do not understand the intention behind using `str_to_a32`, but just on the basis of "plugging things in that fit", `aescipher = AES.new(bytes,AES.MODE_ECB)` might work.

Comment: Please put code that is vital to answering the question in the question itself, keekers. Questions should be self contained.

Comment: @unutbu you're somewhat right, since i'm porting someone elses javascript code. i've fixed the problem now though using struct.pack()

Answer (score 2):

You should not supply any kind of list/array when creating an AES key. The raw key bytes are normally supplied using a byte array of `keysize / 8` bytes. For AES, the only key sizes that are supported are 128, 192 and 256 bits or 16, 24 and 32 bytes respectively.

Note that padding keys until they fit may lead to major cryptographic vulnerabilities. So is using ECB mode instead of a more secure mode like CBC (or one that also provides authentication/integrity protection such as GCM of course).