# Pycrypto, list into AES key generator

Tags: python, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass list to AES key generator in PyCrypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539360/pass-list-to-aes-key-generator-in-pycrypto)

I'm making a wrapper for an API by porting JavaScript to Python.

It passes a list as the key into an AES generator e.g:

```
[1885434739, 825373440, 0, 0]
```

However this gives me the error:

```
TypeError: 'list' does not support the buffer interface
```

Does anyone know how I can get Pycrypto AES encryption working with a list as the key, since it's an API I can't change it's requirement that the input is a list. Thank you.

example of current code:

```
test_key = [1885434739, 825373440, 0, 0]
aes = AES.new(test_key, AES.MODE_ECB)
print(aes)
```

Comment: @keekers: I'll admit I chuckled, because I am quite juvenile. However, the powers that be on this site frown about those sorts of comments. More on topic, why do you need another question to ask the same thing?

Comment: GregS: I forgot i asked the question before, and just happened to be stuck on the same thing again. Anyway, fixed it now using AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, '\0' * 16)